# iptables allow host for isolated VLAN

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, port-forwarding

I'm having a real trouble trying to do a "simple" tweak in my network. So:

- there are two sites, A and B and are connected via IPsec and there's no problem in communication between them.
- each site has two VLANs, main and guest: main is `192.168.55.0/24` for A and `192.168.88.0/24` for B and guest is `192.168.10.0/24` for both.
- VLANs are isolated on each router via this rule (example for A):

`iptables -A forward -s 192.168.10.0/24 -d 192.168.55.0/24 -j DROP`

NOW the problem: I want to allow specific host in A/guest to reach a specific host in B/main. How do I do that?

I've tried just putting
`iptables -A forward -s 192.168.10.10 -d 192.168.55.55 -j ACCEPT`, but it does not work – I can see some packets, but connection does not work (it's an webserver with SSL at 443). I guess I need to add something to mangle/postrouting chain?

Thank you

Comment: For one your `ACCEPT` rule needs to be *appended* (`-A`) before the `DROP` rule is, because `192.168.55.0/24` covers `192.168.55.55`.

Comment: @TomYan that's true, I've put it before isolation one. I suspect I need something in mangle/prerouting because replies from target host do not reach guest back

Comment: Well, do you have `ACCEPT` rule for the replies? (Either stateful or stateless) As for whether you need source NAT / IP masquerade, it really depends on your exact setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that both guest networks share the same address range. If there is only a `forward` rule, the packet from A/guest will reach its destination in B/main, but the return packets will physically be sent to B/guest.

So you need the router at `A` to `MASQUERADE` this connection, so the host at B/main will see the `192.168.55.0/24` as source and know how to return the return packets. When such a packet reaches the router at A, it will automatically rewrite the destination to the original guest host, and forward the packet accordingly.

This should do the trick (apply on the router at site `A`):

`iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.10.10 -d 192.168.55.55 -j MASQUERADE`

Comment: Thank you!! I had this thought before seeing your answer, and I'm happy to see your solution. I've discovered that I only have route for A/main <-> B/main for my IPsec connection, so not only same address space was the issue, but also packets couldn't physically reach the other site. So I've changed address space and added a dedicated route on B for replies to the target host and boom it's working now. I'll test your rule as well, I hope router hw will be enough for doing this on high traffic though. Thanks again!

Comment: With masquerading, the routing for A/main <=> B/main through the VPN would be sufficient. However, the downside is that your service at B/main cannot see the original source IP address of the client. So I'd say assigning distinct address ranges to each of the guest networks will probably be the better solution anyways. You're welcome, happy that you solved your issue!